# Changing font size in Rmarkdown presentation using revealjs

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

Just a quick query about the revealjs options one can use to create slides. I love a lot of its features but I'm unable to figure out if I can change the font size of text globally. The `<small>` html tag makes it possible to make certain sections smaller, but I'd like to know if there's an option to specify something perhaps in the YAML header for the whole slide deck. I believe CSS might be my answer but I'm genuinely confused at the various options in CSS to change font size.

Any help hugely appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
    revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
        css: styles.css
---

## Test slide

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

```{r}
head(mtcars)
```
````

The content of `styles.css` looks like this

```
.reveal section p {
    font-size: 0.5em;
}

.reveal section pre code {
    font-size: 0.7em;
}
```

This changes the font size globally

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much! I tried that and it changed the font size of all my code but not the text, but I sort of guessed the p in the css file was for the html element paragraphs and changed to ul because all my slides only have lists and it worked perfectly! Thanks again.